# Wordpress: Disable plugin in attachment page

Tags: wordpress

I Have plugin for image lazy load, and i need to disable this plugin in any attachment page.

How can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default admin has the access to manage the plugins page in WP.

But you can make this accessible by public also.
Just need to add a capability to subscriber role

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the subscriber role
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    //add capability to this role
    $role->add_cap( 'activate_plugins' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

`activate_plugins` is a capability provided to admin user only by WordPress.

but we can add the capability to any other user role. And Subscriber is considered as the public of WP site, So this code will do the needful.

**Note :** This can be dangerous in terms of security.